# OLE DB or ODBC error in Microsoft PowerBI while importing data from Azure Synapse

Tags: powerbi, odbc, ole, azure-synapse

I am trying to import a view (having 700M rows)from Azure Synapse in Microsoft Power BI, while it works intially and imports around 70M rows successfully but the connection gets dropped after that and following error appears.
Can Someone help me here?
[image]

Comment: Does the issue happen in Power BI desktop or Power BI service? If it's in Power BI desktop, please share desktop trace log.  If it's later one, please share gateway log files.

Comment: This happens in power bi desktop

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is a dedicated SQL pool in Synapse.

If that's the case, I would suggest checking the following, in this order:

1. Intermittent connection issues if the query is taking some time to complete. You can test that with several tools, including command prompt.
2. Check service availability in the Azure Synapse resource, under the left menu "Diagnose and solve problems."
3. Optimise the query
4. Check your Azure Synapse firewall settings

Another test you can do is to temporarily change the view to return less records, to isolate the problem.